# Movesense upgrading to Firmware version 1.2.0 -instructions missing

Tags: firmware, movesense

Following the Movesense sampling rate issue I reported in my previous question, I am trying to update the device firmware to the new release "1.2.0" to see if it can resolve the issue. My system is Windows 64bit.
There seem to be missing instructions on how to upgrade to this version or maybe I did not find them:
I have made the installations according to:

"Automated setup on all operating systems using Vagrant"

Which are:

1. Get Vagrant for your platform
2. Get Virtualbox (easiest way to run and
   manage VMs)
3. Clone this repository and run vagrant up - this will
   pull the ubuntu image and set up the environment necessary to
   develop Movesense software. This should take around 3 minutes.
4. Once the box is up, run vagrant ssh in the directory. You will be taken
   to the fully set up environment and ready to start developing. A
   great place to go next is Example application build flow below

   Then I did as instructed:

   ninja dfupkg

I get the following error message:

```
ninja: error: loading 'build.ninja': No such file or directory
```

I also did the manual installation under "Manual setup on Windows".
Being in the cloned repository I also tried 
    ninja dfupkg
To receive similar error message.

I guess there is some build and make to do before I can do the packing. However I did not find anywhere in the instructions how to do it in order to upgrade to the new release "1.2.0".

Can you assist?

By the way, why not supply the required .zip file: "movesense_dfu.zip" in the repository; and thus get rid of the need to spend hours and install many unrequired tools for those who only want a firmware update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cmake is generating ninja build.ninja file. And this step is missing to compile the sample. Please, read Readme.md file.

> Can you assist?
>   By the way, why not supply the required .zip file: "movesense_dfu.zip" in the repository; and thus get rid of the need to spend hours and install many unrequired tools for those who only want a firmware update?

I do not understand. Did you check the repo?

All ready samples you can always find here:
https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-device-lib/src/ffa04199dd4af314324b43b3ed927dba0559e9be/samples/bin/?at=master

Comment: Thanks, but I did read the Readme.md file and I am still missing something. In the location you gave there are many .zip files. Which .zip file do I need in order to make a full firmware upgrade to : "1.2.0"? I want to use the sample application on my mobile to upgrade the firmware. From all the .zip files which one should I take for full upgrade? or should I generate a new .zip file?

Comment: All zips from the "bin" directory (for version 1.2) contain the new bootloader. If you do not want to change sample app by adding own providers but only default providers, the best sample will be hr_wakeup (release version). It is waiting for connection 60 sec and goes sleep - to wake up you have to use connector and short circuit with fingers.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you skipped some steps from the "Example application build flow" paragraph.

From Movesense inctruction:

```
Example application build flow
    > git clone git@bitbucket.org:suunto/movesense-device-lib.git
    > cd movesense-device-lib
    > mkdir myBuild
    > cd myBuild

To build a debug version of a selected sample application (hello_world app in this example):
    > cmake -G Ninja -DMOVESENSE_CORE_LIBRARY=../MovesenseCoreLib/ -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../MovesenseCoreLib/toolchain/gcc-nrf52.cmake ../samples/hello_world_app
    > ninja

To build a release version:
    > cmake -G Ninja -DMOVESENSE_CORE_LIBRARY=../MovesenseCoreLib/ -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../MovesenseCoreLib/toolchain/gcc-nrf52.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ../samples/hello_world_app  
    > ninja
```

After above steps you can do ninja dfupkg.

Comment: Of course I skipped these steps in the exampled steps the build is for "Hello World" in your answer: end of the first command line: ../samples/hello_world_app. How do I do it for release "1.2.0" - it is not clear what should I write instead of "Hello World". I do not want to render my Sensor useless! Since Documentation for Movesense is slim would be happy for some more elaboration.